# excel vba columns to listbox

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

I'm looking to populate an Excel VBA userform listbox with values from Sheet 1, Row 1 with a dynamic number of columns in the sheet (columns can range between 22 and 30 columns).

So far I have the following code, but it only populates the value of cell "A1" in the listbox.

```
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim lCol As Long

'Determine last column
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Set range source data to be included in listbox
Set rngSource = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lCol))

'Populate listbox with range source data
lstAllFields.List = rngSource.Cells.Value
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Change your statement which says

```
ListBox1.List = rngSource.Cells.Value
```

to be

```
ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(rngSource.Cells.Value)
```

so that the cells are treated as if they were a column of values instead of a row of values.

---

As pointed out in a comment by A.S.H, you also have unqualified properties (i.e. things like `Cells` where you don't specify which worksheet that the property is referring to, and therefore it defaults to the active sheet).  These can cause problems as soon as you start needing to use more than one worksheet in your macro, so it is better to get into the habit of fully qualifying things now.

At the moment, your code (after my suggested correction above) is equivalent to:

```
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim lCol As Long

'Determine last column
lCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Set range source data to be included in listbox
Set rngSource = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(1, lCol))

'Populate listbox with range source data
lstAllFields.List = Application.Transpose(rngSource.Cells.Value)
```

The use of `Cells` belonging to the `ActiveSheet` as the bounds for a `Range` on `Worksheets("Sheet1")` works fine while `ActiveSheet` and `Worksheets("Sheet1")` are the same thing, but will crash if they are different.

I would recommend the use of a `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` block, which just allows us to syntactically shortcut all occurrences of `Worksheets("Sheet1")` to simply `.`.  Your code would then look like:

```
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim lCol As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")    
    'Determine last column
    lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Set range source data to be included in listbox
    Set rngSource = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lCol))

    'Populate listbox with range source data
    lstAllFields.List = Application.Transpose(rngSource.Cells.Value)
End With
```

Comment: @A.S.H - You must have been watching me!  I posted the update and then I went to upvote your comment, but it was already gone.